# I want to create a file that been given name by the user and save some image in it ? in php

Tags: php, html, fopen

i want to create a file.The name of the file is given by the user.So i take the textfield value to $name and how can i save a file with that name? i know how to save with a static name like

```
 $myfile="ads.txt"
```

so my question is.is there a way that i can create a file with the name $name and save some stuff in it like image.

Comment: May I ask why the name is given by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$file = fopen($name, 'wb'); // for the love of God and all that is holy, please validate $name
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: @Danny You even linked `fopen` in your questions tags. What was it you were having trouble with?

Comment: my trouble is i want to save images that user upload into a user named file this is the problem i dont know how to put variables for example if he is going to upload hotel picture i want to upload it into a file named:the hotel name so asd hotel has a file name asd and has pictures in it @phil

Answer (score -1):

You can't save images in a txt file.
What you must do is save the actual image to your server (uploaded via a file field) and save to a database the location and name of the image, along with the user id, so you know who uploaded it.

There is quite a large amount of code involved, so i would suggest googling for "php file upload tutorial", plenty of examples out there.

Comment: You most certainly can save image data into a file with `.txt` extension

Comment: Sure, you can also save them in a database, but that doesn't make it the proper way to do it. Danny is obviously very new to this, so as in most cases, the simplest answer is the right one.